# Storing more number of images in file on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to develop the solution where storing of image data downloaded from server and display it.

Scenario is, There will be thumbnail images placed on each row, clicking on that will download the actual image from server and display the image in a bigger view.

I want to store this image data once its downloaded from server, so that in the later stage if the same thumbnail has clicked to open, I don't need to again download the actual image from server, instead I can pull that from the place where I stored locally.

There will be more than 80 thumbnail images placed in rows and corresponding bigger images on the server.

Can I store the image data in a file and store it in documents directory or some thing like that? My worry, if the user selected all the 80 thumbnail images, then i'll have to store all the 80 bigger images locally on the app.

What is the best way to achieve this storing solution? Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the images in the documents folder, as you already said. Just make sure to exclude them from backups, Apple will reject you for storing too much replaceable data in there.

There are also some third party image cache libraries, most notably (afaik) FastImageCache from Path:
https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

From their website what FastImageCache does is this:

> - Stores images of similar sizes and styles together
> - Persists image data to disk
> - Returns images to the user significantly faster than traditional methods
> - Automatically manages cache expiry based on recency of usage
> - Utilizes a model-based approach for storing and retrieving images
> - Allows images to be processed on a per-model basis before being stored into the cache